# C# TcpClient Connection Retry

Tags: c#

I don't understand what information I have available to me with async operations in C# even after reading the docs. I have a TpcClient and I want it to try to connect x number of times. So far:

```
    public async Task SocketConnect() {
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        for(int i = 0; i < maxConnectionAttempts; i++) {
            OpenSocket();
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }

    private void OpenSocket() {
        try {
            tcpClient.BeginConnect(host, port, ConnectCallback, tcpClient);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
        try {
            tcpClient.EndConnect(result);

            // Connected
            if (tcpClient.Connected) {
                Console.WriteLine("connected");
                if (OnClientEvent != null)
                    OnClientEvent(this, new ClientEventArgs(Action.Connect));

                stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

                BeginReadAsync();
            }
            // Not connected
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("not connected");
                Console.WriteLine("Retrying");
            }
        }            
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I'm missing the logic in the `SocketConnect()` method. I'm not sure how I could `await` `OpenSocket()` because its result is carried to a different callback. What can I return from `OpenSocket()` so that I know it connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a muddle you've gotten into.

You're mixing two different types of asynchrony... the [Task Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the (considerably more confusing) [Asynchronous Programming Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I suggest you ditch APM (it's old and sh*t) and stick with TAP from herein, because it allows you to write asynchronous code ***without*** callbacks so you end up much simpler, readable code.

If I understand correctly, all you're trying to do is this:

```
public async Task SocketConnect() {
    var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    for(var retries = 0; retries < 5; retries++)
    {
        try
        {
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //handle errors
            continue;
        }
        if(tcpClient.Connected) break;
    }
    if(tcpClient.Connected)
    {
        //yay
    }
}
```